# Aren't both the statements same in this Python Threading documentation

Tags: python, multithreading

In [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.shutdown) Python Threading Executor shutdown documentation, I'm having tough time to understand what is it intended to tell.

> shutdown(wait=True, *, cancel_futures=False)
>
> Signal the executor that it should free any resources that it is using when the currently pending futures are done executing. Calls to Executor.submit() and Executor.map() made after shutdown will raise RuntimeError.
>
> If wait is True then this method will not return until all the pending futures are done executing and the resources associated with the executor have been freed. If wait is False then this method will return immediately and the resources associated with the executor will be freed when all pending futures are done executing. Regardless of the value of wait, the entire Python program will not exit until all pending futures are done executing.

The first statement says,

1. If `wait` is True then this method will not return until all the pending futures are done executing and the resources associated with the executor have been freed.

And the second statement says,

2. If `wait` is False then this method will return immediately and the resources associated with the executor will be freed when all pending futures are done executing.

So, technically, if there are 10 pending futures to run, according to first statement (`wait=True`),

1. The `shutdown` method will not return **until** all the 10 futures are **done executing**.

according to second statement (`wait=False`),

2. The `shutdown` method will return immediately **when** all the 10 futures are **done executing**.

So both of them waited for those 10 futures to complete the execution and then only returned. Then what is the difference between `wait=True` and `wait=False`?

Comment: You are mis-reading.  Wait=False says return immediately.  Wait=True says to wait until the processes are done to return.  In either case, the executor is not freed until all the pending futures are finished.  The only difference is whether you're waiting for that to happen.

Comment: It sounds like Waiting only controls when the return happens.

Comment: Put another way.  shutdown(wait=True) says "I can't continue until I know this thing is completely shutdown, so I'm going to wait for that to happen".  shutdown(wait=False) says "I got other stuff to do.  I trust that this thing will eventually finish, but I don't need to wait for it to happen.".

Comment: OK @FrankYellin, Your second way of interpretation makes some sense. But what the final result will be? Will the main script terminates even before some of the futures, say, 5 out of 10 hasn't completed yet?

Comment: These "futures" are themselves a way to sync two independent threads/processes, so if you need the result (which may not be the case), you have to wait for the according value anyway.

Comment: Shortly, `shutdown(wait=True)` will block the calling thread, but `shutdown(wait=False)` will not block the calling thread. Sometimes we need both of them